# Issue in running migrations on postgres db while using typeorm version 0.3.17 in typescript

Tags: typescript, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I am using oops class based code structure and below is my code snippet

dataSourceProvider.ts

```
export class Postgres {
  private static instance: Postgres;
  private postgresDataSource: DataSource;

  private constructor() {}

  public static getInstance(): Postgres {
    if (!Postgres.instance) {
      Postgres.instance = new Postgres();
    }
    return Postgres.instance;
  }

  async connect(): Promise<void> {
    if (!this.postgresDataSource?.isInitialized) {
      this.postgresDataSource = new DataSource({
       type: 'postgres',
       host: '**',
       port: 3306,
       username: '**',
       password: '**',
       database: '**',
       synchronize: false,
       logging: true,
       entities: [__dirname + '../../entities/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
       migrations: [__dirname + '../../migrations/*{.ts,.js}'],
       connectTimeoutMS: 60000,
      });
      try {
        await this.postgresDataSource.initialize();
        logger.info('POSTGRES_CONNECTION_SUCCESS');
      } catch (e: any) {
        logger.error('POSTGRES_CONNECTION_ERROR', { error: e.message, stack: e.stack });
        throw new Error('POSTGRES_CONNECTION_ERROR');
      }
    }
  }
  
  getConnection(): DataSource {
    return this.postgresDataSource;
  }
}
```

test.entity.ts

```
@Entity('test_db')
export class EntityClass {
  @Column()
  testcolumn1: string;

  @Column()
  testcolumn2: string;

}
```

How can I generate migrations and run them to create tables via migrations. to run typeorm migration it requires datasource object exporting file path but I am using class based structure and not able to use migration options.